# How to get the value from a column of a dataframe with the key of another column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe with two columns A (char) and B (num). I want to find the corresponding value of B, for a value of A.

For example, I have the following data, and I want to find the value from column B for "b" and assign it to some variable val. We don't know the order of a,b,c,d so we want to use the character given.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yvgx.png)

So val = 5

Answer (score 0):

We can create a logical vector with column 'A', subset the 'B' values and assign (`<-`) it  to an object 'val'

```
df<-data.frame("A"=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), "B"=c(3, 5, 8, 2))

val <- with(df, B[A=='b'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` :

```
val <- df$B[match('b', df$A)]
```